# unable to handle err properly in return function

Tags: go

That code sends parallel request to a host, if I send a valid host that program work fine, but if I send a invalid host after 10 execution, that program stop working. but this program
already returning err in struct. and main function not handling correctly, I am unable to find out
why this program stop after returning 10 invalid result. it is not returning 100 result.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sort"
    "time"
        
)

// a struct to hold the result from each request including an index
// which will be used for sorting the results after they come in
type result struct {
    index int
    res   http.Response
    err   error
        
}

// boundedParallelGet sends requests in parallel but only up to a certain
// limit, and furthermore it's only parallel up to the amount of CPUs but
// is always concurrent up to the concurrency limit
func boundedParallelGet(urls []string, concurrencyLimit int) []result {

    // this buffered channel will block at the concurrency limit
    semaphoreChan := make(chan struct{}, concurrencyLimit)

    // this channel will not block and collect the http request results
    resultsChan := make(chan *result)

    // make sure we close these channels when we're done with them
    defer func() {
        close(semaphoreChan)
        close(resultsChan)
    }()

    // keen an index and loop through every url we will send a request to
    for i, url := range urls {

        // start a go routine with the index and url in a closure
        go func(i int, url string) {

            // this sends an empty struct into the semaphoreChan which
            // is basically saying add one to the limit, but when the
            // limit has been reached block until there is room
            semaphoreChan <- struct{}{}

            // send the request and put the response in a result struct
            // along with the index so we can sort them later along with
            // any error that might have occoured
            res, err := http.Get(url)
                        if err != nil {
                            fmt.Println(err)
                            return

                        }
                        
                       
                        fmt.Println(res.Status)

            result := &result{i, *res, err}

            // now we can send the result struct through the resultsChan
            resultsChan <- result

            // once we're done it's we read from the semaphoreChan which
            // has the effect of removing one from the limit and allowing
            // another goroutine to start
            <-semaphoreChan

        }(i, url)
    }

    // make a slice to hold the results we're expecting
    var results []result

    // start listening for any results over the resultsChan
    // once we get a result append it to the result slice
    for {
        result := <-resultsChan
        results = append(results, *result)

        // if we've reached the expected amount of urls then stop
        if len(results) == len(urls) {
            break
        }
    }

    // let's sort these results real quick
    sort.Slice(results, func(i, j int) bool {
        return results[i].index < results[j].index
    })

    // now we're done we return the results
    return results
}

// we'll use the init function to set up the benchmark
// by making a slice of 100 URLs to send requets to
var urls []string

func init() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        urls = append(urls, "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/")
    }
}

// the main function sets up an anonymous benchmark func
// that will time how long it takes to get all the URLs
// at the specified concurrency level
//
// and you should see something like the following printed
// depending on how fast your computer and internet is
//
// 5 bounded parallel requests: 100/100 in 5.533223255
// 10 bounded parallel requests: 100/100 in 2.5115351219
// 25 bounded parallel requests: 100/100 in 1.189462884
// 50 bounded parallel requests: 100/100 in 1.17430002
// 75 bounded parallel requests: 100/100 in 1.001383863
// 100 bounded parallel requests: 100/100 in 1.3769354
func main() {
        
    benchmark := func(urls []string, concurrency int) string {
                
        startTime := time.Now()
        results := boundedParallelGet(urls, concurrency)
        seconds := time.Since(startTime).Seconds()
        tmplate := "%d bounded parallel requests: %d/%d in %v"
                
               
        return fmt.Sprintf(tmplate, concurrency, len(results), len(urls), seconds)
    }
       
           
        

    fmt.Println(benchmark(urls, 10),"hello")
  
    fmt.Println(benchmark(urls, 25))
    fmt.Println(benchmark(urls, 50))
    fmt.Println(benchmark(urls, 75))
    fmt.Println(benchmark(urls, 100))
}
```

output

```
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on  no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
Get "https://qapur.extspt.example.com/": dial tcp: lookup qapur.extspt.example.com on : no such host
```

after printing 10 result it is stop process
how can i process 100 url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `Get` triggers an error, you immediately return without removing the blocking item from the channel.

You could either remove the blocking item here or remove the `return` and actually store a pointer to a `http.Response` in the struct (this way you can store `nil` from the failed requests).

Here is the code of your for loop using the second method, note the printing of the status is now in an `else` as it could be nil.

```golang
// a struct to hold a pointer to the result from each request
// including an index which will be used for sorting the
// results after they come in
type result struct {
    index int
    res   *http.Response
    err   error
}

// ...

// keen an index and loop through every url we will send a request to
    for i, url := range urls {

        // start a go routine with the index and url in a closure
        go func(i int, url string) {

            // this sends an empty struct into the semaphoreChan which
            // is basically saying add one to the limit, but when the
            // limit has been reached block until there is room
            semaphoreChan <- struct{}{}

            // send the request and put the response in a result struct
            // along with the index so we can sort them later along with
            // any error that might have occoured
            res, err := http.Get(url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            } else {
                fmt.Println(res.Status)
            }

            result := &result{i, res, err}

            // now we can send the result struct through the resultsChan
            resultsChan <- result

            // once we're done it's we read from the semaphoreChan which
            // has the effect of removing one from the limit and allowing
            // another goroutine to start
            <-semaphoreChan

        }(i, url)
    }
```